# How do I get the log of a node container?

Tags: docker

```
npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /root/.npm/_logs/2021-09-15T14_03_26_179Z-debug.log
npm ERR! code ENOENT
npm ERR! syscall open
npm ERR! path /package.json
npm ERR! errno -2
npm ERR! enoent ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/package.json'
npm ERR! enoent This is related to npm not being able to find a file.
npm ERR! enoent
```

I tried:

```
root@admin-vbox:/media/projects/admin# docker-compose exec node bash 
Error response from daemon: Container 1db9578fbcd06f68a66bd05e2f4f9dd346f889d2e33607be993760fbc9246df6 is restarting, wait until the container is running
root@yanik-vbox:/media/projects/admin#
```

So I can't go inside the container, because it keeps restarting. Is there a way to check what's inside the log?

I also tried:

```
docker logs admin_node1
```

But it just gives me the log above, without all the details.